# Custom Plugin for PhoneGap Windows8 that will call c# code

Tags: cordova, windows-8, phonegap-plugins, sensors

I want to develop an application that will display sensor data in both windows8 and android.
I'm using phoneGap for some sensors, but, for example, barometer, there is no implementation in phoneGAP.
I want to develop a plugin for cordova-windows8. but there is no example in the web for how to do it.
I want to call c# function that uses Microsoft.codePack API for sensors in order to display the barometer data.
the ApiCodePack uses windows 7 API for sensors.
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

is there any option to develop a plugin for cordova-windows8 that will call c# code?
a sample application will be appreciate.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you can call C# code in phone gap

You need to refer [Plugin development](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) Guide

sample plugin for calculator

HTML CODE :calculator.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=2.0, maximum-scale=4.0, minimum-scale=1.0" / -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> <!-- ISO-8859-1 -->
    <title>Cordova</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-current.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var deviceReady = false;

    /**
    * Function called when page has finished loading.
    */
    function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
            deviceReady = true;
            console.log("Device=" + device.platform + " " + device.version);
        }, false);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            if (!deviceReady) {
                alert("Error: Cordova did not initialize.  Demo will not run correctly.");
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    function calculateSum() {

        cordova.exec(
            function (res) {
                document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = res;
            },
            function (e) {
                console.log("Error occurred: " + e);
                document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = "Error occurred: " + e;
            },
            "Calculator", "sum",
            { x: document.getElementById('x').value, y: document.getElementById('y').value });
    };

</script>

  </head>
  <body onLoad="init();" id="stage" class="theme">

    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <div id="info">
        <span class='tb-label'>X</span> <span id="Span1"></span>
        <input type="text" id="x" value="1" style="width:250px;height:20px;"/>
        <br/>
        <span class='tb-label'>Y</span> <span id="Span2"></span>
        <input type="text" id="y" value="2" style="width:250px;height:20px;"/>
        <br/>
        Sum: <span id="res"></span>
    </div>
    <h2>Action</h2>
    <a class="btn large" onclick="calculateSum();">Calculate</a>
    <h2> </h2><a href="index.html" class="backBtn">Back</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

C# Code :calculator.cs

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON;

namespace Cordova.Extension.Commands
{
    public class Calculator : BaseCommand
    {

        [DataContract]
        public class CalculateParameters
        {
            [DataMember]
            public double x { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public double y { get; set; }
        }

        public void sum(string args)
        {
            CalculateParameters calcParam = JsonHelper.Deserialize<CalculateParameters> (args);

            this.DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, calcParam.x + calcParam.y));
        }
    }
}
```

enjoy custom plugin for c#

Comment: I see here WPCordovaClassLib reference. can I add this reference to windows8 application? it is not windows phone application...

Comment: I have configured for W8 phone app.I am not sure about Windows8 application. but phone gap [support](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides) Windows 8 so you need to check same.