# Can We Call C# Library dll from Apache Cordova?

Tags: c#, .net, cordova

My azure table storage having table named as User where I have stored user information.

I have core class library which contains business logic for fetching data from azure.

My web application uses this library.

Now I want to create mobile app using Cordova.

Can I give reference of class library dll & call functions using ajax in cordova.
If not what is the way to accomplish this task?

Related question is what should I do to fetch record from azure table storage in Cordova app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Apache Cordova** is a platform for building native mobile applications using **HTML, CSS and JavaScript**

So no, you can't call .NET assemblies directly on the client. You have to put them in [a plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide). You can find some samples for Windows Phone [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_windows-phone_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Windows%20Phone). Another sample in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16057029/993547).

Comment: I want to fetch records from azure table storage can you give me any suggestions about how should I do this??

Comment: @MangeshKulkarni: No, I am not familiar with that. Maybe there is an OData service available you could use in javascript?

Comment: MS Provides a Cordova stater app to aide in connections between the two.