# Can a Cordova plugin make calls to a .Net Framework .dll?? Not WinRT Component (.Net Core)?

Tags: c#, .net, cordova, plugins, windows-runtime

I have a .dll that was written to target the .NET Framework.  I need to create a Cordova plugin that can make calls to this .dll.

Our Cordova App runs on a Windows 10 Tablet.

Because this .dll targets .NET Framework and not .NetCORE, I cannot take the approach of a WinRT component that's suggested in all of the guidance I've seen.

Is it possible to have a Cordova plugin that makes calls to a .NET Framework .dll and if so can you recommend a correct approach?

Disclaimer:  I'm in the weeds with Cordova.  I'm learning as I go.  An EXAMPLE would be overwhelmingly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No on both form and function. You'll need to use a .Net library that works with .Net Core for UWP.

Form:
Cordova apps on UWP run in the native JavaScript environment, not in a WebView hosted in a C# app. The only way for a UWP JavaScript app to call .Net functions is via a Windows Runtime Component (WRC).

While you could (in theory) write a version of Cordova for Windows Runtime that uses a .Net hosted WebView I'm not aware of any existing ones. (The Windows Phone 8 versions Hassan Ali linked do use a Silverlight WebBrowserControl, but don't run on Windows 10 tablets).

Function:
Even if you did change the Cordova host to .Net so it could call .Net directly without a WRC that would still run in the UWP context.

UWP apps can use only NetCore, not the full .Net Framework, whether they are direct .Net apps or call .Net inside a WRC.

Comment: Rob thanks for your reply.  After thinking this through and more thoroughly understanding the differences between the frameworks, I realized the question was somewhat of a dumb question to ask.

I've taken a different approach.  On the tablet I've setup a REST service.  Calls will be made to that service...and the service will make calls to the .NET Framework .dlls.

Thanks for your input.  I believe this answers the question fully so I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Apache Cordova** is a platform for building native mobile applications
>   using **HTML, CSS and JavaScript**

So no, you can't call .NET assemblies directly on the client. You have to put them in a [plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide). You can find some samples for Windows Phone [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_windows-phone_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Windows%20Phone). Another sample in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056439/custom-plugin-for-phonegap-windows8-that-will-call-c-sharp-code/16057029#16057029).